# How to compare two lists of dicts for multiple key, value pairs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two `list`s of `dict`s, one is a modified subset of the other. I would like to get the elements of `list_one` that don't appear in `list_two`, based on two keys.  Example:

```
list_one = [{'name': 'alf', 'age': 25},
            {'name': 'alf', 'age': 50},
            {'name': 'cid', 'age': 30}]
list_two = [{'name': 'alf', 'age': 25, 'hair_color': 'brown'},
            {'name': 'cid', 'age': 30, 'hair_color': 'black'}]
desired_list = [{'name': 'alf', 'age': 50}]
```

How can I accomplish this? I have a feeling it is with some sort of `list` `comprehension`, as such:

```
desired_list = [x for x in list_one if x['name'] != x2['name'] and x['age'] != x2['age'] 
                for all x2 in list_two]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is easily done with two comprehensions as:

#### Code:

```
have_2 = {(d['name'], d['age']) for d in list_two}
extra = [d for d in list_one if (d['name'], d['age']) not in have_2]
```

This first creates a `set` of `tuple`s which we already have, then checks which `dict`s do not match any of these existing keys.

#### Test Code:

```
list_one = [{'name': 'alf', 'age': 25},
            {'name': 'alf', 'age': 50},
            {'name': 'cid', 'age': 30}]
list_two = [{'name': 'alf', 'age': 25, 'hair_color': 'brown'},
            {'name': 'cid', 'age': 30, 'hair_color': 'black'}]

have_2 = {(d['name'], d['age']) for d in list_two}
extra = [d for d in list_one if (d['name'], d['age']) not in have_2]

print(extra)
```

#### Results:

```
[{'name': 'alf', 'age': 50}]
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, along with a helpful explanation + formatting. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Yet another possible solution:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: not any([set(x.items()).issubset(y.items()) for y in list_two]), list_one))
[{'age': 50, 'name': 'alf'}]
```

or:

```
>>> s2 = [set(i.items()) for i in list_two]
>>> list(filter(lambda x: not any([set(x.items()).issubset(y) for y in s2]), list_one))
[{'age': 50, 'name': 'alf'}]
```

The advantage of this approach is that it does not need to know the "keys" ('age' and 'name') present in both dictionary sets.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this:-**

```
new_list = [i for i,j in zip(list_one,list_two) if i['name']!=j['name'] and i['age']!=j['age']]
print (new_list)
```

### Output

> [{'name': 'alf', 'age': 50}]

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way would be to convert your two structures to dicts, keyed by the two values, then create the result dict:

```
key = lambda dct: (dct['name'], dct['age'])
d1 = { key(dct): dct for dct in list_one }
d2 = { key(dct): dct for dct in list_two }
desired_d = { k:v for k,v in d1.items() if k not in d2 }
print(desired_d)
print(desived_d.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
diff = [
    e for e in list_one
    if (e['name'], e['age']) not in set((e['name'], e['age']) for e in list_two)
]
print diff
```